# How to find the sublattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let say I have this equation,

Yt+1=Yt +sign(Xt)

Xt+1=Xt+a(Yt+1)+b where a,b are integers and 0 < b < a.

If gcd(a,b)=d, then how can I find the sublattice by looking at the coordinates? This is really confusing.

Let say I choose any point [x,y]= [50,10], depending on the gcd(a,b), the coordinates change. I need to find the conjugacy equation that can simplify the case of gcd(a,b)=d to gcd(a/d,b/d)=1 which makes me really confusing!

Comment: Is this really regarding [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29)? Or is it about [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) instead?

Comment: this is about the lattices where I need to find the sublattice so that I can simplify the whole thing from gcd(a,b)=d to gcd(a,b)=1. Basically  I need to find the conjugacy equation.